# Inverse relationship on Child's child

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, relationship

I'm trying to use core data relationships to make an an inverse relationship work between a child's child object.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a number of filing cabinets, each filing cabinet has number of drawers, each drawer has a number of files.

- Filing cabinet has a to-many to Drawer
- Drawer has an inverse to Filing cabinet
- Drawer has a to-many to File
- File has an inverse to Drawer

> When I add a file to a drawer the drawer sets itself as the inverse on
>   the file however, I want an automagic **cabinet** inverse on a a file too. So i can do something like `[file cabinet]` as well as the standard `[file drawer]` Right now,
>   I can't create this particular inverse.

I know I could use `[[file drawer] cabinet]` but this is a simple example for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just add a method to your `NSManagedObject` subclass?

```
- (Cabinet *)cabinet;
{
    return self.drawer.cabinet;
}
```

Comment: I could write some code like you have done here (my real use-case could have up to 5 children) but I'm looking almost for a Core Data setting to cascade a relationship without code

Comment: I don't believe there is such an option and to be fair it kind of breaks the law of Demeter, you will end up have  a messy object graph where every object knows too much about other objects.

Comment: All I want is to have the ability to predicate a fetch like: (name contains[cd] "File NAME") && (cabinet == {CabinetObject}). Your saying that breaks law of Dementer?

Comment: Performing a search using different conditions is fine, asking the objects to know about distantly related objects most likely would.

Comment: To perform the above predicate I need File to know what cabinet it's in.

Comment: File does not really need to know this itself (you can figure it out), this leads to brittle design. There is a subtle difference between `file.cabinet` and `file.drawer.cabinet`. What happens if you change your design to include archive boxes as well? e.g. `file.archiveBox.cabinet`. Your initial `file.cabinet` would now be broken...

Comment: Indeed, my real problem is that file *could* be: `file.compartment.compartment.compartment.compartment.cabinet` (1 or more compartments). And I don't know how to do that in a predicate other than file knowing it's cabinet. Because if I calculate it, how can I query a file object in core data with that calculation if it dosn't have the prop?